# Virtual Host using Apache

Tags: apache

We have development team of 10 people working on Linux platform our application is hosted on Apache server

Now what i want if every developer is having own codebase in his directory

he can have his own httpd conf file which uses his code base and his port on that server

and whenever he changes the code base he needs run only his apache process

and there is no need to start , restart the apache server as other people should not get disturbed

so can we do this listening same server on different ports with different DocumentRoot and no need to start or restart the whole apache server only individual process of apache need to be started if any changes are done in the local conf file of that user

Answer (score 1):

You need not get into the complexity of managing virtual hosts.
You can create alias for each developer which will point to his directory.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Eg :

servername.com/dev1/

in httpd conf point dev1 to developer's working folder.

Developer can update code see the result at the above url without restarting server.